# Why can I insert a number into a VARCHAR2 column?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, casting, insert

I have an odd problem with a table, I'm inserting rows into tables, and now I am trying to test it, on one of my tests it allows an entry that it shouldn't.

My table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE ITEMS(
ITEM_NUMBER VARCHAR2(3)
CONSTRAINT ITEMS_ITEM_NUMBERf_PK PRIMARY KEY,
ITEM_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(30),
ITEM_SIZE VARCHAR2(2),
ITEM_COST NUMBER(30,0),
ITEM_QTY NUMBER(2,0),
ORDER_NUMBER VARCHAR2(4));
```

When I try and test the `ITEM_SIZE` column by putting in a `number` it just inserts it.

```
INSERT INTO ITEMS VALUES ('I32', 'Leather blazer', 'L', 14.00, 1, 'O114');
INSERT INTO ITEMS VALUES ('I33', 'Fleece vest', 'L', 28.00, 1, 'O128');
INSERT INTO ITEMS VALUES ('I34', 'Khaki pants', 'S', 22.00, 3, 'O122');
INSERT INTO ITEMS VALUES ('I35', 'Muscle Tee', 'M', 12.99, 1, 'O122');
INSERT INTO ITEMS VALUES ('I36', 'Trench Coat', 'M', 03.00, 1, 'O133');
INSERT INTO ITEMS VALUES ('I37', 'Crewneck sweater', 'XL', 07.00, 1,   'O107');
INSERT INTO ITEMS VALUES ('I38', 'Varsity Sweater', 'M', 08.99, 1, 'O108');
INSERT INTO ITEMS VALUES ('I39', 'CROOK', 'M', 12.00, 1, 'O112');
```

//--the tester--//

```
INSERT INTO ITEMS VALUES ('I49', 'bROOK', 10, 12.00, 1, 'O112');
```

In the statement above I insert the number 10 into `ITEM_SIZE VARCHAR2(2)`. How can I avoid that?

Comment: Just  a minor you have typed ITEM_SIZEf  instead of ITEM_SIZE (probably)

Comment: yeah my bad sorry was from testing my table before

Comment: but still having the issue

Comment: I don't understand your question  please explain better

Comment: when i add the tester table it has as on the third value (10) , where that should be a varchar2 and come up with an error

Comment: The `NUMBER` 10 can be (and is implicitly) cast into `VARCHAR2(2)` `'10'`.

Comment: its slightly changed code from the one immediately above//--the tester--//

Comment: hmmm i do not want a number in that field though, what could i do to change it?

Comment: Create a check constraint.

Comment: I'm fairly noobish what kind of constraint would i need?

Answer (score 3):

As @kevinsky said, [Oracle is doing implicit data conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements002.htm#SQLRF00214) from number to string while you insert.

If you want to restrict the values that can be put into a column then you can add [a check constraint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/clauses002.htm):

```
alter table items add constraint items_size_chk
  check (item_size in ('XXS','XS','S','M','L','XL','XXL','XXXL'));

Table ITEMS altered.

INSERT INTO ITEMS VALUES ('I49', 'bROOK', 10, 12.00, 1, 'O112');

SQL Error: ORA-02290: check constraint (SCHEMA.ITEMS_SIZE_CHK) violated
02290. 00000 -  "check constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    The values being inserted do not satisfy the named check
```

If you want different restrictions you can change the way the check is done; for example you could have a regular expression check to exclude digits but allow any characters. In this case it seems more likely you want a list of specific values to be allowed though.

Note though that when a new valid size is added, you will have to modify the check constraint; and any of those size values will be allowed for any item.

If the valid sizes are coming from another table then you can use a foreign key constraint instead. You probably really want a list of sizes (or other attributes) that are valid for each item, so your data model might need some fleshing out.

Comment: What Alex says in the last paragraph is the correct solution to this type of problem.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle is implicitly converting the number 10 into the varchar2 string '10'.

and here is another implicit conversion

```
SELECT item_size + 1  FROM items;
```

Result in Oracle 11g is

11

I'm not sure whether this was intended to be helpful when the parser was being built but it does cause a lot of confusion.  However Oracle will not convert an alphabetical character into a number implicitly. It will fail.